# How can we use laravel dusk with browserkit?

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

We started using Dusk but have existing test suites that use Browserkit. Because Browserkit testing is faster than using Dusk, we do not want to convert our existing test suites.

However, when using both Dusk and Browserkit testcases in the same run, the Dusk tests fail with an error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1
>   no such table: users (SQL: select * from "users" where "users"."id" =
>   1 and "users"."deleted_at" is null limit 1)

When we run them alone, Dusk test cases work.

I realize it's related to the setup of the tests but have not succeeded in either reusing the DB setup/connection or resetting properly in the BaseTestCase, and I haven't seen traces of people doing it. I'm pretty sure it can be done but how not to "break" laravel phpunit testing?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You could use
`trait DatabaseMigration`

Comment: Bit of explanation is always good in answers. With your rep you should know.